# Javascript object serialisation with toSource() converts special chars to hex code - how to reverse?

Tags: javascript, serialization, utf-8, object, special-characters

If I'm converting a simple JavaScript object to a string, all special chars will be converted to hex code.

```
function O() {
    this.name = "<üäö!";
}
var myObject = new O();
console.log(myObject.toSource());
```

Result:

```
{name:"<\xFC\xE4\xF6!"}
```

How would I avoid this or convert all hex chars back to utf8 chars?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Crockford's [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js), you completely avoid this issue.

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

outputs

```
{"name":"<üäö!"}
```

You can then send this string, e.g. using an `XMLHttpRequest` (in that case, don't forget to use [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Functions/encodeURIComponent)).